# How to report the result a mixed model effects in a scientific article

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

Let's say I have data of a chemistry expriment: I have a sample of 11 probe coming from comparable material (ID01 to ID11, the random effect).
I make process them with 2 different reactants (reactant A and Reactant B, 2 different fixed effect).
There are 10 difference concentrations of reactant A and 3 different concentrations of reactant B.
I finally read a measurement and want to determine the effect of reactant A and reactant B.
The assumption is that the concentration of reactant A has an effect on the measurement, whereas reactant B does not.
I simulated data accordingly.

Part of the output is the following:

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  117.005      7.137  16.393
Reac_A_num    45.821      0.499  91.827
Reac_B_num    -1.177      1.939  -0.607
```

Here are my questions:

1. The absolute value of the estimate of Reac_A_num is greater than its Std. Error. Therefore, Reactant A seems to have an effect on the Outcome. Correct?
2. The absolute value of the estimate of Reac_B_num is smaller than its Std. Error. Therefore, Reactant B does not seem to have an effect on the Outcome. Correct?
3. If 1. and 2. are correct, how can one appropriately report those data in a scientific manuscript (as there are no "p-values")?

Here is the output

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: Outcome ~ Reac_A_num + Reac_B_num + (1 | ID)
   Data: dfcombined

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2958.2   2976.8  -1474.1   2948.2      303 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.66638 -0.72172  0.01047  0.72722  3.14272 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 269.7    16.42   
 Residual             772.2    27.79   
Number of obs: 308, groups:  ID, 11

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  117.005      7.137  16.393
Reac_A_num    45.821      0.499  91.827
Reac_B_num    -1.177      1.939  -0.607

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) Rc_A_n
Reac_A_num -0.420       
Reac_B_num -0.541 -0.001
```

Here is the data set (in .csv format):

```
,ID,Reac_A,Reac_B,Outcome,Reac_A_num,Reac_B_num
0,ID01,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,175.96317549009538,1.0,1.0
1,ID02,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,182.2550618307917,1.0,1.0
2,ID03,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,143.91730930128176,1.0,1.0
3,ID04,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,131.6026369230803,1.0,1.0
4,ID05,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,148.19896459063142,1.0,1.0
5,ID06,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,130.09909959523614,1.0,1.0
6,ID07,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,146.56051256005466,1.0,1.0
7,ID08,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,141.57541963406646,1.0,1.0
8,ID09,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,149.58182187731092,1.0,1.0
9,ID10,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C01,193.91890183411255,1.0,1.0
10,ID11,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,190.33253022629935,2.0,1.0
11,ID01,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,207.37340937821955,2.0,1.0
12,ID02,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,,2.0,1.0
13,ID03,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,193.83089509653644,2.0,1.0
14,ID04,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,224.96359043837634,2.0,1.0
15,ID05,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,168.9277996502002,2.0,1.0
16,ID06,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,,2.0,1.0
17,ID07,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,177.11754211599552,2.0,1.0
18,ID08,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,228.46319787577542,2.0,1.0
19,ID09,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C01,194.59408911471948,2.0,1.0
20,ID10,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,224.93705465058832,3.0,1.0
21,ID11,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,239.81392794785458,3.0,1.0
22,ID01,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,268.36046471890825,3.0,1.0
23,ID02,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,306.6263050417395,3.0,1.0
24,ID03,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,215.78721903203765,3.0,1.0
25,ID04,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,264.5583036472632,3.0,1.0
26,ID05,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,,3.0,1.0
27,ID06,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,210.14827334408938,3.0,1.0
28,ID07,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,256.13323688501544,3.0,1.0
29,ID08,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C01,283.9991271496295,3.0,1.0
30,ID09,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,277.08503014205894,4.0,1.0
31,ID10,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,267.903873003556,4.0,1.0
32,ID11,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,281.3834178629039,4.0,1.0
33,ID01,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,,4.0,1.0
34,ID02,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,344.4271256530111,4.0,1.0
35,ID03,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,295.4412126363893,4.0,1.0
36,ID04,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,294.913964681868,4.0,1.0
37,ID05,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,279.0643560110288,4.0,1.0
38,ID06,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,265.73528808279366,4.0,1.0
39,ID07,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C01,269.594369031282,4.0,1.0
40,ID08,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,318.4978493512993,5.0,1.0
41,ID09,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,300.25815322306994,5.0,1.0
42,ID10,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,317.15900636894696,5.0,1.0
43,ID11,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,316.49810940434634,5.0,1.0
44,ID01,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,344.3703277261114,5.0,1.0
45,ID02,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,400.73832961881646,5.0,1.0
46,ID03,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,307.347866227025,5.0,1.0
47,ID04,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,359.6985341083482,5.0,1.0
48,ID05,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,349.6635070827579,5.0,1.0
49,ID06,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C01,314.3505809182711,5.0,1.0
50,ID07,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,339.3288205287455,6.0,1.0
51,ID08,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,369.276080590692,6.0,1.0
52,ID09,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,360.3857108994122,6.0,1.0
53,ID10,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,356.37934634764,6.0,1.0
54,ID11,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,368.71427173610505,6.0,1.0
55,ID01,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,424.8919327312468,6.0,1.0
56,ID02,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,447.77690494713124,6.0,1.0
57,ID03,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,397.24117528127516,6.0,1.0
58,ID04,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,409.5610092882836,6.0,1.0
59,ID05,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C01,409.84568484610554,6.0,1.0
60,ID06,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,366.10759468419167,7.0,1.0
61,ID07,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,375.58983850030506,7.0,1.0
62,ID08,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,424.925637139781,7.0,1.0
63,ID09,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,409.5605892723437,7.0,1.0
64,ID10,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,412.1493832561823,7.0,1.0
65,ID11,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,438.29488046013114,7.0,1.0
66,ID01,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,459.0904934575327,7.0,1.0
67,ID02,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,509.5730545010236,7.0,1.0
68,ID03,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,436.31133674925707,7.0,1.0
69,ID04,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C01,474.3985618234745,7.0,1.0
70,ID05,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,445.85919943449176,8.0,1.0
71,ID06,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,446.78098117824663,8.0,1.0
72,ID07,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,436.07093823665923,8.0,1.0
73,ID08,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,448.05246729255606,8.0,1.0
74,ID09,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,484.47105833287037,8.0,1.0
75,ID10,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,475.28623289390043,8.0,1.0
76,ID11,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,490.1614537977487,8.0,1.0
77,ID01,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,524.8742753611798,8.0,1.0
78,ID02,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,553.117235354672,8.0,1.0
79,ID03,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C01,455.74873612940326,8.0,1.0
80,ID04,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,527.7077201985376,9.0,1.0
81,ID05,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,487.17119575570837,9.0,1.0
82,ID06,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,488.1533401962364,9.0,1.0
83,ID07,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,489.0328612758312,9.0,1.0
84,ID08,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,496.40742171645616,9.0,1.0
85,ID09,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,,9.0,1.0
86,ID10,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,532.56564773395,9.0,1.0
87,ID11,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,492.0629677918874,9.0,1.0
88,ID01,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,572.5594461512935,9.0,1.0
89,ID02,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C01,588.3646944328207,9.0,1.0
90,ID03,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,526.364342594615,10.0,1.0
91,ID04,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,574.5303622287228,10.0,1.0
92,ID05,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,532.5390770818364,10.0,1.0
93,ID06,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,,10.0,1.0
94,ID07,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,549.7940269273572,10.0,1.0
95,ID08,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,535.3471348466327,10.0,1.0
96,ID09,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,586.148609110255,10.0,1.0
97,ID10,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,588.4265192761819,10.0,1.0
98,ID11,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,591.7855939629035,10.0,1.0
99,ID01,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C01,600.3192258875238,10.0,1.0
100,ID02,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,628.8892368256597,11.0,1.0
101,ID03,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,596.6412106335927,11.0,1.0
102,ID04,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,615.074165337679,11.0,1.0
103,ID05,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,567.9755977178145,11.0,1.0
104,ID06,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,597.0070121070032,11.0,1.0
105,ID07,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,606.3198305608295,11.0,1.0
106,ID08,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,630.707299481629,11.0,1.0
107,ID09,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,625.2529853544906,11.0,1.0
108,ID10,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,610.0952214989439,11.0,1.0
109,ID11,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C01,592.9134581323192,11.0,1.0
110,ID01,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,163.0947810916,1.0,2.0
111,ID02,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,175.40717115239784,1.0,2.0
112,ID03,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,181.6757774227178,1.0,2.0
113,ID04,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,157.49923701575278,1.0,2.0
114,ID05,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,160.87897823788632,1.0,2.0
115,ID06,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,149.9227018367978,1.0,2.0
116,ID07,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,119.0322974678176,1.0,2.0
117,ID08,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,201.32589035962877,1.0,2.0
118,ID09,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,199.72191356510584,1.0,2.0
119,ID10,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C02,225.13143123417257,1.0,2.0
120,ID11,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,180.189589558541,2.0,2.0
121,ID01,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,213.79571356719362,2.0,2.0
122,ID02,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,229.73876035471687,2.0,2.0
123,ID03,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,240.1213090822149,2.0,2.0
124,ID04,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,202.99916965232646,2.0,2.0
125,ID05,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,241.9260725758565,2.0,2.0
126,ID06,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,230.84150488548977,2.0,2.0
127,ID07,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,203.30128753977385,2.0,2.0
128,ID08,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,276.27506038513997,2.0,2.0
129,ID09,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C02,243.6251624306043,2.0,2.0
130,ID10,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,268.88966450756345,3.0,2.0
131,ID11,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,249.76155124412082,3.0,2.0
132,ID01,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,284.05893262218075,3.0,2.0
133,ID02,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,269.282305134721,3.0,2.0
134,ID03,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,280.6541003562467,3.0,2.0
135,ID04,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,250.08290055864364,3.0,2.0
136,ID05,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,268.2776774554918,3.0,2.0
137,ID06,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,246.97295832081502,3.0,2.0
138,ID07,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,261.15603294667596,3.0,2.0
139,ID08,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C02,316.8266580827621,3.0,2.0
140,ID09,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,,4.0,2.0
141,ID10,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,316.40792668666796,4.0,2.0
142,ID11,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,272.2695794164,4.0,2.0
143,ID01,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,315.00773094069035,4.0,2.0
144,ID02,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,297.4619449972508,4.0,2.0
145,ID03,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,,4.0,2.0
146,ID04,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,310.6044472652657,4.0,2.0
147,ID05,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,297.60363104852473,4.0,2.0
148,ID06,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,293.3535945837459,4.0,2.0
149,ID07,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C02,311.8844944544687,4.0,2.0
150,ID08,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,372.54824325955434,5.0,2.0
151,ID09,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,383.62324801824843,5.0,2.0
152,ID10,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,359.36045189004966,5.0,2.0
153,ID11,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,327.85876933184977,5.0,2.0
154,ID01,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,397.69539144291997,5.0,2.0
155,ID02,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,368.8278140497438,5.0,2.0
156,ID03,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,412.0278702683967,5.0,2.0
157,ID04,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,351.0515690015452,5.0,2.0
158,ID05,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,,5.0,2.0
159,ID06,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C02,357.53098627708755,5.0,2.0
160,ID07,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,351.76171766946663,6.0,2.0
161,ID08,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,431.5358020507246,6.0,2.0
162,ID09,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,411.5215514470504,6.0,2.0
163,ID10,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,424.455851691988,6.0,2.0
164,ID11,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,371.80841056316507,6.0,2.0
165,ID01,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,,6.0,2.0
166,ID02,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,439.008517979492,6.0,2.0
167,ID03,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,439.91287424424064,6.0,2.0
168,ID04,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,401.1288429486718,6.0,2.0
169,ID05,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C02,394.0433218413809,6.0,2.0
170,ID06,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,408.79052469358476,7.0,2.0
171,ID07,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,405.75078508310776,7.0,2.0
172,ID08,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,462.1378751411957,7.0,2.0
173,ID09,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,472.10133678400916,7.0,2.0
174,ID10,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,429.9382323866242,7.0,2.0
175,ID11,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,429.36175597917565,7.0,2.0
176,ID01,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,465.2208074595036,7.0,2.0
177,ID02,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,,7.0,2.0
178,ID03,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,475.8229302301139,7.0,2.0
179,ID04,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C02,465.7585274653326,7.0,2.0
180,ID05,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,490.9041036293007,8.0,2.0
181,ID06,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,452.899705296328,8.0,2.0
182,ID07,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,438.938018835665,8.0,2.0
183,ID08,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,498.98859501673553,8.0,2.0
184,ID09,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,516.7947826333289,8.0,2.0
185,ID10,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,522.4803392815998,8.0,2.0
186,ID11,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,488.35176146429575,8.0,2.0
187,ID01,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,525.3686475440222,8.0,2.0
188,ID02,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,510.4202171076454,8.0,2.0
189,ID03,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C02,570.0013095040155,8.0,2.0
190,ID04,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,504.85572031036577,9.0,2.0
191,ID05,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,494.03244524385883,9.0,2.0
192,ID06,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,534.4767844601406,9.0,2.0
193,ID07,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,486.8322427529967,9.0,2.0
194,ID08,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,561.0334582208496,9.0,2.0
195,ID09,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,570.494368858899,9.0,2.0
196,ID10,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,,9.0,2.0
197,ID11,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,559.1350600216866,9.0,2.0
198,ID01,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,576.975350749215,9.0,2.0
199,ID02,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C02,590.3325387539585,9.0,2.0
200,ID03,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,586.1069585859476,10.0,2.0
201,ID04,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,,10.0,2.0
202,ID05,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,586.028330247162,10.0,2.0
203,ID06,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,547.953860838981,10.0,2.0
204,ID07,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,556.0888505803584,10.0,2.0
205,ID08,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,620.9138942037202,10.0,2.0
206,ID09,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,601.2040007870337,10.0,2.0
207,ID10,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,607.6378431407547,10.0,2.0
208,ID11,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,564.0397341846999,10.0,2.0
209,ID01,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C02,612.0884583130163,10.0,2.0
210,ID02,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,595.1765333884033,11.0,2.0
211,ID03,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,645.1580615389514,11.0,2.0
212,ID04,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,621.6264613393256,11.0,2.0
213,ID05,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,636.2141133284828,11.0,2.0
214,ID06,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,625.4985561581013,11.0,2.0
215,ID07,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,578.0689854981267,11.0,2.0
216,ID08,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,647.8317777416929,11.0,2.0
217,ID09,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,649.528787301419,11.0,2.0
218,ID10,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,,11.0,2.0
219,ID11,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C02,632.5020343266629,11.0,2.0
220,ID01,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,146.97493484684983,1.0,3.0
221,ID02,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,125.61957415253706,1.0,3.0
222,ID03,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,149.0604831676189,1.0,3.0
223,ID04,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,192.2714115297376,1.0,3.0
224,ID05,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,138.8991715438839,1.0,3.0
225,ID06,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,156.96903359624045,1.0,3.0
226,ID07,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,131.72309167776334,1.0,3.0
227,ID08,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,169.14345319692657,1.0,3.0
228,ID09,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,211.46296940717878,1.0,3.0
229,ID10,Reac_A01,Reac_B_C03,136.6457478798518,1.0,3.0
230,ID11,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,105.17728977644256,2.0,3.0
231,ID01,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,188.19523464263122,2.0,3.0
232,ID02,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,196.2121622981528,2.0,3.0
233,ID03,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,153.28281051360707,2.0,3.0
234,ID04,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,206.51841316389954,2.0,3.0
235,ID05,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,,2.0,3.0
236,ID06,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,237.96042611029145,2.0,3.0
237,ID07,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,205.4256015738578,2.0,3.0
238,ID08,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,227.39158288956727,2.0,3.0
239,ID09,Reac_A02,Reac_B_C03,230.37933646885932,2.0,3.0
240,ID10,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,179.6109296511914,3.0,3.0
241,ID11,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,165.06081726348071,3.0,3.0
242,ID01,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,279.2361015972373,3.0,3.0
243,ID02,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,227.6779284738138,3.0,3.0
244,ID03,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,,3.0,3.0
245,ID04,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,262.53573961397234,3.0,3.0
246,ID05,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,239.13380045843078,3.0,3.0
247,ID06,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,301.3398588469872,3.0,3.0
248,ID07,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,240.54071686142836,3.0,3.0
249,ID08,Reac_A03,Reac_B_C03,284.4585902795619,3.0,3.0
250,ID09,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,310.4077610036021,4.0,3.0
251,ID10,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,234.35403509799673,4.0,3.0
252,ID11,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,228.0152006433636,4.0,3.0
253,ID01,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,,4.0,3.0
254,ID02,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,284.9559079604275,4.0,3.0
255,ID03,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,,4.0,3.0
256,ID04,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,327.18071979818944,4.0,3.0
257,ID05,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,279.68368752763587,4.0,3.0
258,ID06,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,306.5915294247452,4.0,3.0
259,ID07,Reac_A04,Reac_B_C03,292.0562767221174,4.0,3.0
260,ID08,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,325.76484017345075,5.0,3.0
261,ID09,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,321.24175683147774,5.0,3.0
262,ID10,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,,5.0,3.0
263,ID11,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,281.2551341654206,5.0,3.0
264,ID01,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,351.94280924878,5.0,3.0
265,ID02,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,368.5476188873796,5.0,3.0
266,ID03,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,341.8355492055789,5.0,3.0
267,ID04,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,364.04177166053637,5.0,3.0
268,ID05,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,323.0299218988586,5.0,3.0
269,ID06,Reac_A05,Reac_B_C03,390.1678988354298,5.0,3.0
270,ID07,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,,6.0,3.0
271,ID08,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,367.625525407548,6.0,3.0
272,ID09,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,417.8720247554286,6.0,3.0
273,ID10,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,334.62462763318837,6.0,3.0
274,ID11,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,303.41497294829946,6.0,3.0
275,ID01,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,430.9348197838297,6.0,3.0
276,ID02,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,409.788241924328,6.0,3.0
277,ID03,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,367.83326496456624,6.0,3.0
278,ID04,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,422.8138240082898,6.0,3.0
279,ID05,Reac_A06,Reac_B_C03,367.0586586328404,6.0,3.0
280,ID06,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,423.7519612159338,7.0,3.0
281,ID07,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,366.8337445014016,7.0,3.0
282,ID08,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,423.33900008552064,7.0,3.0
283,ID09,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,428.48236122114463,7.0,3.0
284,ID10,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,408.6456122649899,7.0,3.0
285,ID11,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,367.07256391101924,7.0,3.0
286,ID01,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,438.34753126483776,7.0,3.0
287,ID02,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,460.19000058067576,7.0,3.0
288,ID03,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,440.2794731457531,7.0,3.0
289,ID04,Reac_A07,Reac_B_C03,473.4820259490547,7.0,3.0
290,ID05,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,448.236223413948,8.0,3.0
291,ID06,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,485.4138562942793,8.0,3.0
292,ID07,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,,8.0,3.0
293,ID08,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,457.30139747831976,8.0,3.0
294,ID09,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,484.15655965142287,8.0,3.0
295,ID10,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,438.7131133994853,8.0,3.0
296,ID11,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,434.6167005717717,8.0,3.0
297,ID01,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,524.9277318122961,8.0,3.0
298,ID02,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,499.65484785577985,8.0,3.0
299,ID03,Reac_A08,Reac_B_C03,483.08011985782855,8.0,3.0
300,ID04,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,505.44986934410025,9.0,3.0
301,ID05,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,485.3244474321928,9.0,3.0
302,ID06,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,554.5465283108877,9.0,3.0
303,ID07,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,,9.0,3.0
304,ID08,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,519.809083602265,9.0,3.0
305,ID09,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,539.036511395827,9.0,3.0
306,ID10,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,525.692360658201,9.0,3.0
307,ID11,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,461.1528648736348,9.0,3.0
308,ID01,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,585.6229481511847,9.0,3.0
309,ID02,Reac_A09,Reac_B_C03,556.9817611381593,9.0,3.0
310,ID03,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,542.7707351514649,10.0,3.0
311,ID04,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,576.0743543470179,10.0,3.0
312,ID05,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,557.3848743997728,10.0,3.0
313,ID06,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,582.8426122743225,10.0,3.0
314,ID07,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,545.6470525612091,10.0,3.0
315,ID08,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,587.9823905922478,10.0,3.0
316,ID09,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,584.1761167212139,10.0,3.0
317,ID10,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,563.6969546659843,10.0,3.0
318,ID11,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,541.2617643845715,10.0,3.0
319,ID01,Reac_A10,Reac_B_C03,609.9847661164207,10.0,3.0
320,ID02,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,598.4004814215971,11.0,3.0
321,ID03,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,594.3873760271308,11.0,3.0
322,ID04,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,630.9431874067878,11.0,3.0
323,ID05,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,576.5135367339814,11.0,3.0
324,ID06,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,630.4830312968793,11.0,3.0
325,ID07,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,580.5753749591622,11.0,3.0
326,ID08,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,603.3769997275527,11.0,3.0
327,ID09,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,650.806486288947,11.0,3.0
328,ID10,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,623.4467116409456,11.0,3.0
329,ID11,Reac_A11,Reac_B_C03,561.0237102000497,11.0,3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically there should be an associated degree of freedom so that you can compute the p value yourself.  There doesn't seem to be a degree of freedom in the output, so you can use an alternative appraoch.

Rather than reporting p values (which are fairly uninformative anyway), you can report profile likelihood confidence intervals by running

```r
confint(model)

                2.5 %     97.5 %
.sig01       10.724457  27.512360
.sigma       25.694947  30.182029
(Intercept) 102.598167 131.388478
Reac_A_num   44.839211  46.802100
Reac_B_num   -4.989523   2.637222
```

Note here that the interval for `Reac_A_num` excludes 0, so the associated test would reject the null hypothesis.  On the other hand, the interval for `Reac_B_num` includes 0, so the associated test would fail to reject this null.

As for reporting, it generally depends on the context of the problem, but you could say something to the effect of

> A unit change in Reac_A_num was associated with an expected change of 45.821 in the outcome (95% CI: (44.83 -- 46.80).  A unit change in Reac_B_num was associated with an expected change in the outcome of -1.177 , however the observed association is consistent with a null effect (95% CI: (-4.98 -- 2.63))

Or something like that.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @demetripananos